# Create a C++ class and Use that class In Another C++ Class Which contain JNI methods in ndk android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, native

In Android, I am facing issues in connecting two cpp class in native Android. I have tested with the single class it working fine.

but when I have created another file and now facing an issue in linking it with current cpp file.

**MainClass.cpp**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "native-handler.h"

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_fragment_SampleFragment_setTitle(JNIEnv *env,jobject instance,jobject context) {

    ClassNativeHandler classNativeHandler;
    return classNativeHandler.getType(env,context);
}
```

**native-handler.cpp**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "native-handler.h"

jstring jstringObject;

jstring ClassNativeHandler::getType(JNIEnv *env, jobject contextObject) {
    jstring jstringObject = env->NewStringUTF("Hello world");
    return jstringObject;
}

void ClassNativeHandler::setType(jstring string) {
    myType = string;
    jstringObject = string;
}
```

**native-handler.h**

```
#ifndef SAMPLE_NATIVE_HANDLER_H
#define SAMPLE_NATIVE_HANDLER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class ClassNativeHandler
{
private:
    jstring myType;

public:
    void setType(jstring string);
    jstring getType(JNIEnv *env, jobject contextObject);
    jstring getHeaderName(JNIEnv *env);

};

#endif //SAMPLE_NATIVE_HANDLER_H
```

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := Native
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../cpp/mainClass.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := ../cpp/native-handler.h
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lz -llog -ljnigraphics
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Error : undefined reference to `ClassNativeHandler::getType(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)'

on this line
**return classNativeHandler.getType(env,context);**

So I am not able to build the .so file. Please guide me

Comment: What does this question have to do with Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't compiled `native-handler.cpp`. You need to specify it in `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` so that NDK compiles it.

`LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../cpp/mainClass.cpp ../cpp/native-handler.cpp`

Comment: Now I can Compile the file, But get error on running the application like { JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of deleted local reference 0x7f5bc55a3d }

Comment: Inside `ClassNativeHandler::getType` you have defined local `jstring jstringObject` effectively shadowing the global `jstringObject` that might cause the invalid local reference error.

Comment: It is not stored in the memory when pointing again to the location getting null so getting error on **ClassNativeHandler::getType** Which is using locai variable **jstring jstringObject**